SwiftData fetch performance problem with relationships
Trying to solve performance issues with SwiftData.
When I add one-to-many relationship to my model, performance drastically degrades.
Code below.
To reproduce just add more than 5-6 thousands of models.
@Model
class EnterChild {
    @Relationship
    var enterModel: EnterModel?
    
    init(enterModel: EnterModel? = nil) {
        self.enterModel = enterModel
    }
}

@Model
class EnterModel {
    
    @Relationship(inverse: \EnterChild.enterModel)
    var enterChildren = [EnterChild]()

    var name: String
    
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

struct EnterView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext)
    private var mc
    
    @State
    var models: [EnterModel] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Text("\(models.count)")
                .onTapGesture {
                    for i in 1...5000 {
                        let em = EnterModel(name: "Model number \(i)")
                        mc.insert(em)
                        
                        try? mc.save()
                    }
                }
            
        }
        .onAppear {
                       
            var descriptor = FetchDescriptor<EnterModel>()
            
//            descriptor.propertiesToFetch = [\.name]
//            descriptor.relationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching = [\.enterChildren]
            
            if let result = try? mc.fetch(descriptor) {
                models = result
            }
        }
    }
}

Also in my log I see a lot of queries like this:
CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK FROM ZENTERCHILD t0 WHERE  t0.ZENTERMODEL = ? 
CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 0.0000s
CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.0000s for 0 rows.
CoreData: annotation: to-many relationship fault "enterChildren" for objectID 0x847373e672d56572 <x-coredata://AA52F4C2-B209-45D9-9F04-FE9291706CCD/EnterModel/p6000> fulfilled from database.  Got 0 rows

I believe SwiftData makes query for every EnterModel record.
Using descriptor.relationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching = [.enterChildren] helps reducing amount of queries, but performance remains poor. Also, if in my real app I have relationships in my children model, which starts producing queries when I use prefetching.

It is much better to use FetchRequest for any Model Arrays. You can fetch the children with the persistent id of the parent.

What performance aspect are you referring to? Insert performance or fetching performance?

What is the actual question?

Sorry if my question is unclear.
I'm asking about fetching performance. Fetching more than several thousands  records takes a lot of time (about second on my mac m1). I solved it by adding pagination. But I'm a little confused why is that so, maybe I'm doing wrong. Also when I add relationships to my model it begins to slow down even more (even if I don't use this relations in code)

Try fetchIdentifiers or fetchCount
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/SwiftData/ModelContext
